# ORA-02263: need to specify the datatype for this column

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create table in oracle, and I am getting below error like 'ORA-02263: need to specify the datatype for this column'. I gave datatypes for every column. Don't know what I am missing.

```
CREATE TABLE IUAPORTAL.IUA_PROVIDER_ENROLLMENT (
  ID                    NUMBER              NOT NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ORG_NAME              VARCHAR2(55 BYTE)   NOT NULL,
  ORG_TYPE_ID           VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  CLINICAL_SITES        VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  ADDITIONAL_SITES      VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  CHIRP_SUBMISSION      VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  VFS_PROVIDER          VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  VFS_PIN               VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  SITE_NAME             VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  SITE_CONTACT          VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  PHONE_NUMBER          VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  COUNTY                VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  FAX_NUMBER            VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  EMAIL                 VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  ELECTRONIC_SIGNATURE  CLOB,
  SIGNATURE_DT          DATE,
  NAME_TITLE            VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Comment: I don't htink oracle has auto_increment I think it uses Identity columns so something like `ID Number NOT NULL As IDENTITY`

Comment: That is also not working

Comment: Even if it did have AUTO_INCREMENT, there wouldn't be a comma after NOT NULL - it would be NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, and the NOT NULL would just be redundant, because an AUTO_INCREMENT field can never be null - it's AUTO_INCREMENTed. Here's a thought, though - why not just **read the documentation** to see how it's supposed to be written?

Comment: Ken White, I tried to implement with out comma after NOT NULL - I am getting ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error. I did all google and tried to implement based on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html .. still I am getting issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's both the comma on line 2 and non-Oracle syntax. Try:

```
CREATE TABLE IUAPORTAL.IUA_PROVIDER_ENROLLMENT (
    ID                    NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
    ...
```